# CakePHP callback functions equivalent in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, cakephp

I am new to ASP.Net MVC and was wondering if there are callback functions or methods equivalent to those in CakePHP `beforeFilter()`, `afterFilter()`, `beforeRender()` etc.

What i am trying to do is use the `ViewBag` to set some global variables such as `PageTitle` for example as i have multiple modules sharing the same title and other proprieties.

I also used to have like a parent class -it's called `AppController` in CakePHP which can implement those callback function which enables me to run functions and send variables to my views. I did something like this in ASP.Net MVC but it's useless now since i can't fire up the functions i want to run before `Index()` function runs for example.

AppController.cs

```
public class AppController : Controller
{
    public static string message = "Nice!";

    public void PageInfo()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = message;
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : AppController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        PageInfo();
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I know this sounds silly but being an ASP.Net beginner is a horrible feeling so be easy on me!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom action filter:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // This will run before the action
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Message = "some message";
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // This will run after the action
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // This will run before the result executes
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // This will run after the result executes
    }
}
```

and then decorate either your controller with it (in which case it will apply to all actions in this controller) or to individual actions:

```
[MyActionFilter]
public class HomeController : AppController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin! That's helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to create custom action filter, implementing abstract [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx) and its methods :

- OnActionExecuting
- OnActionExecuted
- OnResultExecuting
- OnResultExecuted

Comment: Hey thanks archil but can you provide example i am kinda lost